# How can I definitively close a PrettyPhoto external iframe (multiple solutions attempted to no avail!)

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

What I would like to accomplish is to close an external iframe that leads back to the indexhtml page of a website I am creating. I have installed a lightbox plugin named Prettyphoto to execute the opening of the iframe from the index page, but I am having tremendous difficulty in closing the iframe. I've searched many forums and threads and have attempted multiple solutions and work arounds, but the iframe still does not close.

```
<a href="index.html" rel="prettyPhoto[iframes]" 
onclick=INSERT SOLUTION VARIANT><img id="close" 
src="http://i43.tinypic.com/2mxrcds.jpg"></a>
```

The following are the below variations of solutions that I have attempted:

`onclick="window.parent.$.prettyPhoto.close();`

`onclick="window.top.location = '/';"`

`onclick="window.top.location = window.parent.location;"`

`onclick="parent.window.close();"`

What I've found is that the window closes within the iframe and does not return to the index.html.

For example, in my index.html page I click a link towards my education.html page which opens in an iframe. When I click the close image it closes the window within the education.html iframe and directs me towards the index.html within the education.html iframe. What I want is for the iframe to "disappear". Are there any other solutions? Am I implementing the solutions incorrectly? Help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where's the code that shows up the window with the iFrame within?

Comment: @MelanciaUK I'm not sure what you mean by the code within the iFrame, do you mean the prettyPhoto script? Also, I seem to have partly solved my problem. On one browser it closes (safari) but doesn't seem to work on Chrome. I am still new to programming but is there a particular reason for this? Just yesterday, I upgraded to mountain lion to address the issue. Is there anything else that I may not be taking into consideration?